# Image Changes with GPIO pins (ON/OFF)

Tags: tkinter, raspberry-pi, gpio, raspberry-pi4

I am using gpio pins as input and when any of the pin is high it should show image the problem is when I run the code first time it works fine but when I ON the other pin it is not changing the image while the code is running. The code I am running is given below:

```
from tkinter import *
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.IN)
input_state1 = GPIO.input(18)
input_state2 = GPIO.input(17)
while True:
    root=Tk()
    root.geometry('1600x900')
    pix=PhotoImage(file='1.png')
    pic=PhotoImage(file='3.png')
    input_state1 = GPIO.input(18)
    input_state2 = GPIO.input(17)
    if input_state1 == True:
        label_pop = Label(root, image=pix)
        label_pop.grid()

    elif input_state2 == True:
        label_pop1 = Label(root, image=pic)
        label_pop1.grid()       
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Note that `root.mainloop()` will not return until the `root` window is closed or destroyed.  `mainloop()` should be called once. Using while loop in your case is wrong, use [`.after()`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/after.htm) function instead.

Comment: I am new to python can you tell where i can use the .after() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `root.mainloop()` will not return until `root` is closed or destroyed, so the first iteration of the while loop will be blocked at the line `root.mainloop()`.  Therefore even there is change on the PIN, no change will be shown or updated.

It is better to run `mainloop()` only once and don't use while loop in the main thread of tkinter application.  For your case, use `.after()` instead.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from RPi import GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.IN)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1600x900')

# assume pix and pic images are loaded somewhere else
#pix = tk.PhotoImage(file='/path/to/pix/image')
#pic = tk.PhotoImage(file='/path/to/pic/image')
blank = tk.PhotoImage()

# create the labels once
label_pop1 = tk.Label(root, width=pix.width(), height=pix.height())
label_pop1.grid(row=0, column=0)

label_pop2 = tk.Label(root, width=pic.width(), height=pic.height())
label_pop2.grid(row=1, column=0)

def check_gpio():
    input_state1 = GPIO.input(18)
    input_state2 = GPIO.input(17)

    # update labels based on reading from PINs
    label_pop1.config(image=pix if input_state1 else blank)
    label_pop2.config(image=pic if input_state2 else blank)

    # call check_gpio one second (1000 ms) later
    root.after(1000, check_gpio)

check_gpio() # start the check loop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Brother i want to show the image in the same row (i.e row 0) even when the did row =0 from row =1 in label_pop2 it show the else (blank)  image kindly guide me through.

Comment: @Hammadzahid It is better to raise another question on that.